# Previous and next links when changing to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating next and previous links, but have run into a spot of bother, as I have changed the way my url looks by modifying the to_param method:

```
 def slug
  name.downcase.gsub(" ", "-")  
 end

 # URL will now show /id-name
 def to_param
  "#{self.id}-#{slug}"
 end
```

So my method to get the previous link looks like:

```
def previous_animal
 self.class.first(:conditions => ["id-name < ?", "what-to-put-here"], :order => "created_at desc")
end
```

Am I right in thinking that if I was just using an id it would be:

```
def previous_animal
 self.class.first(:conditions => ["id < ?", id], :order => "created_at desc")
end
```

How can I pass the new id format?

### Edit

As pointed out by D-side, database lookup is unchanged, so when trying the following I am getting an error:

```
def previous_animal
 self.class.first(:conditions => ["id < ?", id], :order => "created_at desc")
end
```

View

```
<%= link_to(@animal.previous_animal) %>
```

Error:

```
invalid value for Integer(): "{:conditions=>[\"id < ?\""
```

so the link_to is expecting an integer but what is being passed looks something like this:

```
{"id"=>"27-clawd"}
```

Comment: But why? Slugs should only take effect in URL/path helpers, looking up entries in database should be the same, using plain integer `id`. You are fetching an instance of a model that way.

Comment: ah ok, yes good point, ill update my question then with the results of when using id

Comment: I think you'll find it's the first method call that is expecting an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on `id` and `created_at` being in sync, ie assuming a model created after another model will always have a higher ID. It's true in general, but depends on the database and a risky assumption (the ID or created_at can be changed manually, for example).

So I would do something like:

```
def previous_animal
  animal = self.class.order('created_at desc').where('created_at < ?', self.created_at)
  animal.first if animal
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged this as rails 4 but seem to be using rails 2 syntax.

Does this work?

```
def previous_animal
  self.class.where("id < ?", id).order(created_at: :desc).first
end
```

Comment: `.order(created_at: :desc).first` => `.last`?

Comment: @D-side I just used what Rich has used but I think he's right because of the ordering.